# Java Memory Storage to Reduce Database Load - Safe?

Tags: java, mysql

If I have a MySQL table that is not changed very often (once a month) which contains information such as active user accounts for a web service. How safe is it to do something like:

```
public AccountDao
{
   List<Account> accounts;
   /*fields*/
   public AccountDao()
   {
       refreshAccounts();
   }

   public void refreshAccounts()
   {
      this.accounts = /*call to database to get list of accounts*/
   }

   public boolean isActiveAccount(String accountId)
   {
       //logic involving in memory list object above
   }
}
```

I would do this because I have to check a user has an active account for every request to allow access to the web service. This would allow me to avoid one SQL call to the database layer (which is stressed at the moment) on every request. My question is how safe is it to store data like this in production?

By the way, I would refresh the account list whenever a new user account is added via an API call. As stated above, this would happen about once to twice a month.

Comment: This is hard to answer.  It is subjective.  We've done a lot of chaching in our applications and you're right; it can improve performance a lot.  But could it bite you?  Sure!

Comment: What kind of safety are you concerned about? Thread-safety? Confidentiality of credentials? Currency of credentials? ...?

Comment: I am concerned about the data being corrupted. This service generally runs with zero issues for months at a time.

Comment: What data? The list of accounts?

Comment: @meriton I assume everything is safe thread, but perhaps not..

Comment: @thatidiotguy, Just out of curiosity, what is the average time taken to do this query and how many do you get per day?  Have you used an analysis tool to look at any other long-running queries?

Comment: @Jessemon Unfortunately I have very little information because of the business situation here. All I know is that database performance was a big problem earlier in the app's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Access to the shared state in the DAO (and potentially its callers) will need to be synchronized somehow to achieve thread safety.
2. Stale data can cause a wrong access decision. Since that is likely security relevant, your code will need to be bullet proof; in particular, it needs to work reliably in case of failures. This makes any notification based scheme shaky - what if the notification is lost?
3. Lifetime of credentials in memory is prolonged. Confidentiality can still be achieved by hashing the credentials (and frankly, if somebody can read your application's memory, you have many other problems). Manipulation of the password in memory requires the attacker to have access to heap memory, and if he can that, you've lost anyway, because he could just as easily change the database connection used for reading accounts.

That said, for a high-traffic webservice, caching credentials sounds like a sensible idea, but it's not totally trivial.

Edit: No, web containers don't synchronize threads. Concurrent requests will be served by concurrent threads, and if these happen to read and write the same data, that can cause a data race. For instance, one thread could read the list of accounts while it is being updated with new information, and thus see an incomplete list.

Comment: Wouldn't my web application container take care of synchronisation (Tomcat 6 in this case..?) The AccountDao object would be a JavaBean injected by Spring through dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some sort of trigger to update the in-memory object when the corresponding data base tables change then it should be safe.

Without a trigger it becomes a matter of correctness and, potentially, policy. What happens if different part of your infrastructure have different in-memory versions of the database?
How long an interval is acceptable between e.g. adding or removing a user and that change being reflected by your service?

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that is not my concern. We manually add users, so when we add a user using a web form I have the API call to update the in-memory object will go out automatically almost immediately.

Comment: @thkala Do you mean literally a database trigger or are you talking generically?  How would the trigger work?  Are you talking about database caching or caching in the application?

Comment: Its like this: 1) we fill out a web form 2) a different program takes information adds user to database and then sends http request to all web servers informing them to refresh their list of accounts.

Comment: @Jessemon: it *could* be a DB trigger - there are databases that support calling external code within their triggers - but I was speaking more generally. And this point is valid whether the OP uses an intermediate third-party layer (DB caching) or not. Not all database caching solutions support DB updates correctly/efficiently/without-hoop-jumping.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_caching).  Your libraries probably already support it, if not memcached is a good option.

Comment: I am aware of caching, but I think its a little heavy for dealing with just a table or two of data with a couple of columns. Its not like the in-memory object is 2GB or something.

Comment: If your DB is stressed, it's not too heavy.