# Spring Singleton Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

If I have a Java class defined below that is injected in my web application via dependency injection:

```
public AccountDao
{
   private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate njt;
   private List<Account> accounts;

   public AccountDao(Datasource ds)
   {
       this.njt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
       refreshAccounts();
   }

   /*called at creation, and then via API calls to inform service new users have 
     been added to the database by a separate program*/
   public void refreshAccounts()
   {
      this.accounts = /*call to database to get list of accounts*/
   }

   //called by every request to web service
   public boolean isActiveAccount(String accountId)
   {
       Account a = map.get(accountId);
       return a == null ? false : a.isActive();
   }
}
```

I am concerned about thread safety. Does the Spring framework not handle cases where one request is reading from the list and it is currently being updated by another? I have used read/write locks before in other applications, but I have never thought about a case such as above before.

I was planning on using the bean as a singleton so I could reduce database load.

By the way, this is a follow up of the below question:

[Java Memory Storage to Reduce Database Load - Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395884/java-memory-storage-to-reduce-database-load-safe/15396508?noredirect=1#15396508)

EDIT:

So would code like this solve this problem:

```
/*called at creation, and then via API calls to inform service new users have 
         been added to the database by a separate program*/
       public void refreshAccounts()
       {
          //java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock
          final Lock w = lock.writeLock();
          w.lock();
          try{
               this.accounts = /*call to database to get list of accounts*/
          }
          finally{
             w.unlock();
          }
       }

       //called by every request to web service
       public boolean isActiveAccount(String accountId)
       {
           final Lock r = lock.readLock();
           r.lock();

           try{
               Account a = map.get(accountId);
           }
           finally{
               r.unlock();
           }
           return a == null ? false : a.isActive();
       }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring framework does not do anything under the hood concerning the multithreaded behavior of a singleton bean. It is the developer's responsibility to deal with concurrency issue and thread safety of the singleton bean.

I would suggest reading the below article: [Spring Singleton, Request, Session Beans and Thread Safety](http://tarunsapra.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/spring-singleton-request-session-beans-and-thread-safety/)

Answer (score 3):

You could have asked for clarification on my [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395884/java-memory-storage-to-reduce-database-load-safe/15396319#15396319). Spring does not synchronize access to a bean. If you have a bean in the default scope (singleton), there will only be a single object for that bean, and all concurrent requests will access that object, requiring that object to the thread safe.

Most spring beans have no mutable state, and as such are trivially thread safe. Your bean has mutable state, so you need to ensure no thread sees a list of accounts the other thread is currently assembling.

The easiest way to do that is to make the accounts field `volatile`. That assumes that you assign the new list to the field after having filled it (as you appear to be doing).

```
private volatile List<Accounts> accounts;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I felt that it would be disingenuous to the title of the other question to get into that in comments. It is really a separate issue. How does the volatile solution compare to the edited code I put above?

Comment: It's simpler, wait-free and probably a bit more efficient than an explicit lock (though that difference is negligible when comparing it with I/O to a database).

Answer (score 1):

As a singleton and non-synchronized, Spring will allow any number of threads to concurrently invoke `isActiveAccount` and `refreshAccounts`.   So, no this class is not going to be thread-safe and will not reduce the database load.

Comment: Ok, follow up for the accept: Is this fixable easily via code included in this Java class (or application context fixes), or am I better off going for a caching/database solution?

Comment: What you could do is use a temporary list to make the call to the database in `refreshAccounts()`. When that returns, synchronize on `accounts` and reassign it to that list.

Comment: I would say definitely caching/database.  Managing concurrency yourself is difficult.  With the cacheing you can at least have memorizing for concurrency control.  If you really wanted any number of requests I would declare the scope=prototype. Then you run into the load problem you were concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

we have many such meta data and have some 11 nodes running. on each app node we have static maps for such data so its one instance only, init from db at start up once in off peak hour every day or when support person triggers it. have an interal simple http post based API to send updates from 1 node to others for some of the data which we need updates in real time.

```
public AccountDao
{
   private static List<Account> accounts;
   private static List<String> activeAccounts;
   private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate njt;

   static {
       try{
        refreshAccounts();
       }catch(Exception e){
        //log but do not throw. any uncaught exceptions in static means your class is un-usable
       }
   }


   public AccountDao(Datasource ds)
   {
       this.njt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
       //refreshAccounts();
   }

   /*called at creation, and then via API calls to inform service new users have 
     been added to the database by a separate program*/
   public void refreshAccounts()
   {
      this.accounts = /*call to database to get list of accounts*/
   }

   public void addAccount(Account acEditedOrAdded)
   {
      //add or reove from map onr row
      //can be called from this node or other node
      //meaning if you have 2 nodes, keep IP port of each or use a internal web service or the like to tell 
      //node B when a account id added or changed in node A ...
   }   

   //called by every request to web service
   public static boolean isActiveAccount(String accountId)
   {
       Account a = map.get(accountId);
       return a == null ? false : a.isActive();
   }
}
```