# Spring bean singleton bean: multi thread access

Tags: spring, thread-safety, singleton

Singleton beans by design pattern should be of single instance.
Hence, if a thread's execution is on the way of execution blocking a series of beans (say @Controller then @Service then simple beans) one after another

- What will happen if many other simultaneous threads having different functionality but using the same series of beans runs - I mean any conflict situation with data/value may arise or Spring Singleton is thread safe ?

How to resolve the same if not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Singleton Thread Safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396608/spring-singleton-thread-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Controllers, as singleton, aren't thread safety.

I think your singleton beans should be **stateless**.

But you can inject other request or session scoped beans using **proxyMode**, for instance http://healthycoder.in/session-scoped-bean-in-a-controller-spring-mvc/

Comment: this is fine, but my question was limited to within the same session.  Should Spring allow member variable in Singleton scope.. let me create another thread