# Should Spring allow member variable in bean with Singleton scope

Tags: spring, singleton

This is with reference to my another question....
[Spring bean singleton bean: multi thread access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478331/spring-bean-singleton-bean-multi-thread-access?noredirect=1#comment45283490_28478331)

Should Spring allow member variable in bean with Singleton scope ..
reason is...

1. it is Singleton but not synchronized object (not thread safe)
2. With above link reference, multi threads within same session and context accessing the same bean, can create the member variable's undue value

Comment: Please elaborate on your query. Both post aren't intuitive.

Comment: Any framework may not keep any user from doing things which are not appropriate. There is no reason why Spring should forbid the use of members in beans with singleton scope.

Comment: I agree with first sentence.  basically I am not telling for forbidding but was looking for answer or solution to this use case.  Similar think I have for bean's member methods in same scenario - they needed to be used as synchronized.

Comment: What reason has made down-voting this post, I am curious. The question raised in my mind from my thought process ..  what I raised here.

Answer (score 0):

I think .. 
we should use Singleton bean for execution of functionality (methods) only.

We should use Prototype bean for use of its member variable.