# Annotation for synchronize a method in spring

Tags: java, spring, synchronized

I have a simple rest api as below in my rest controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")   
public HttpEntity<String> myService() {
//do something
}
```

Rest Controller is by default singleton and methods are not thread safe (Non synchronized). Is there a annotation define in method level for thread safe (synchronized)?

Comment: You can make the method `synchronized` but why would you want to? That will lead to extremely bad performance.

Comment: maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396608/spring-singleton-thread-safety

Comment: @Joni thanks. i totally forgot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just use the synchronized keyword?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")   
public synchronized HttpEntity<String> myService() {
//do something
}
```

Comment: @John Harris doesn't synchronised only apply if the object is shared by different threads? I thought Spring creates one instance of the controller for each thread?

Comment: Spring controllers are singletons (there is just one instance of each controller per web application) just like servlets. Typically there is no point in changing this behaviour (if it's even possible). @AlexandreCassagne