# Is Spring's @Lazy initialization thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

Hopefully a simple question to answer.  I couldn't find any absolute clear answer on this.  Can anyone please help with a credible source.

I'm going by the general perception that lazy loading is dangerous in a multithreaded application without using a proper synchronized block.  I'm wondering if this is applicable for Spring or not.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Lazily initializing a bean object that connects to a remote database.

Comment: I'm just going by the general perception that lazy loading is dangerous in a multithreaded application without using a proper synchronized block.  I'm wondering if this is applicable for Spring or not.

Comment: Java object initialization is thread safe on its own.

Comment: In the current implementation, for singleton beans, they are initialized in a thread-safe manner. I could not find documentation other than the source code of `DefaultListableBeanFactory`.

Comment: According to the following answer,no .see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396608/spring-singleton-thread-safety

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know anywhere Spring claims for safe publication of the beans managed by IoC container.

However, quick glance through the bean factory/application context code detects that there are a lot of crucial places guarded by synchronization (e.g. registering/unregistering bean definition, post-processing phase etc). See many of the methods in DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry has synchronized blocks.

About lazy initialized beans - i see that inside of DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry, construction is guarded by a lock around singletonObjects instance variable. in addition, singletonObjects itself is a concurrent hash map.

It uses double-checked locking (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton()), so the bean is safely published.

In addition regarding thread safety,i remember spring had bugs previously in initial release and is improved with versions , 
And note that :

1.singleton beans (lazy and non-lazy) are always fully instantiated (including init methods) and safely published. therefore their construction is thread-safe - if another thread does see this bean, it would never see a half-initialized singleton with default values for some fields

2.prototype beans construction is not thread-safe, but usually prototype beans are not shared between threads, and if they have to be - you are on your own to make sure you publish them to other threads safely
this behavior is intended by the framework